# creating triggers in SQL Plus

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have create a database within SQL Plus and I want to implement some triggers, however they do not seem to be working due to the errors, I have searched google for a solution with no avail. Could you guys please help ?

This is what I entered for the trigger.

```
create trigger test
after insert
or update of salary
on staff
for each row

declare
salarygrade number;

begin
select grade
into salarygrade
from salgrade
where :new.salary between losalary and hisalary;


exception
when no_data_found then
raise_application_error(-20001,
'salary not included within in salary grade');
when others then
raise_applciation_error(-20000,
'error has occured');
end;
/
```

The trigger is created but with compilation errors, the errors are:
1. PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "then" when expecting the following.
2. PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting the following.

Comment: Fix your typo (raise_applciation_error should be raise_application_error) and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

i was able to create the trigger, there were some errors in raise application error, i have created it without it, you can modify the changes with the correct syntax of raise_application_error.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger test
    after insert
    or update of salary
    on staff
    for each row

    declare
    salarygrade number;

     begin
     select grade
     into salarygrade
     from salgrade
     where :new.salary between losal and hisal;

     end;
     /

Trigger created.
```

Answer (score 0):

semi-colon missing from

```
and hisalary <= :new.salary
```

Comment: that was a typo my apologies, the error statement went from "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "then" when expecting the following." to this: "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "<" when expecting the following." Why is this happening?

Comment: could you include the CREATE TABLE statements for STAFF and SALGRADE please

Comment: you have another typo, the OTHERS block has incorrect spelling of "applciation". I corrected this and created a couple of dummy tables and it compiles correctly for me.

Comment: I have a table for staff but not for salgrade is this why im getting an error??

Comment: well you certainly will need both the tables, but you would get a "table or view does no exist error" if it was missing

Comment: yeh I haven't got that error I don't even know what is wrong with it.

Comment: create the missing table and try again, then edit the question with your CREATE TABLE and CREATE TRIGGER code and i'll try it again. Also, what version of Oracle are you running?

Comment: post all you code in the question and i can try rerunning it, and what version of oracle are you running?

Comment: i created the database design in another program so if i mess with the code I will have to start the whole db again !!!! oracle 11g

Comment: if i can't see your code then i can't really help, you must be able to copy and paste the CREATE TABLE and TRIGGER statements out of whatever program you are using

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the semi-colon at the end of your select statement.

Whilst we're at it, are you sure that your select statement won't return more than one row? And did you mean `and hisalary >= :new.salary`? (If so, the whole where clause could be rewritten `where :new.salary between losalary and hisalary`)

Comment: I did what you said however in the error where it said: "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "then" when expecting the following." now it says "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "<" when expecting the following." Why is this happening?

Comment: No idea; could you edit your question to add in the amended code? One thing I note from copying your code into my db is that you haven't included a trigger name, which wouldn't help!

Comment: Looking at your current code in the question, I can't see any syntax errors. It fails for me, since I don't have your tables, but I can't see why it wouldn't compile for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CREATE OR REPLACE Trigger to overwrite the old code with the new one.